# Modify files in unmanagedSourceDirectories during build

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-module

I have a multi-module SBT project that writes sources to the unmanagedSourceDirectories during the first module and then subsequently uses the contents during later modules (this process repeats). The project structure looks like this:

```
root
  + gen - writes content to useA/target/generated-sources
  + useA - writes content to useB/target/generated-sources
  + useB - writes content to useC/target/generated-sources
  + etc....
```

The unmanagedSourceDirectories are defined as the following

```
root
  + gen
  + useA - unmanagedSourceDirectories=useA/target/generated-sources
  + useB - unmanagedSourceDirectories=useB/target/generated-sources
  + etc...
```

Is there any way to achieve what I am looking for?